# laravel 4 Illegal offset type in isset or empty

Tags: laravel, store, isset

I am using laravel 4 and trying to perform store of some data. I am having a problem that says:

```
Illegal offset type in isset or empty
     * Get the fully qualified location of the view.
     *
     * @param  string  $name
     * @return string
     */
    public function find($name)
    {
        if (isset($this->views[$name])) return $this->views[$name];

        if (strpos($name, '::') !== false)
```

I can't understand where is this coming from. Anyone that can help me?

Comment: Show us how you are using the method.

Comment: You've pasted us code from laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/FileViewFinder.php, which does not help us help you. We need to see **your** code.

If you don't know what part of your code is making this happen, you should look at the stacktrace for any code that is not in the vendor/ folder.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the $name variable is undefined, are you sure you are setting it?

Comment: this function is not made by me. It is laravel function in …\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\View\FileViewFinder.php69

Comment: You still have to pass in a name.

Answer (score 0):

the type of $name is something that is not a string or an integer

check the var type in newer PHP (5.3>) this is more strict

probably you are sending on $name an object or an array and don't realize

I could reproduce it sending an array 
ie

```
$name = array("test" => "testvalue");

$obj->arr[$name]; //this line give me an error because $name is an array
```

best 
Emiliano